# else operator | JS | Chrome extention

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have this function:

```js
function FizzBuzz(){
   if(document.getElementById("textbox") == true){
      Fizz();
   } else {
      Buzz();
   }
}
```

The `Fizz()` and `Buzz()` functions place text in textboxes specified by `document.getElementById` in their own functions.

in it's current configuration, it should to my understanding execute `Fizz()` if `("textbox")` is found on the webpage, otherwise `Buzz()` should be executed. This does not happen, and it will only execute one of them, no matter if `("textbox")` is true or not.

The `("textbox")` referenced above only exists on one of the two pages this is designed to work with.

Changing to `!== true` will invert the effect, the same with `== false`, as with the current behavior is expected. I have also tried to check for `== null` and `!== null`, this results in the same behavior.

I simply do not understand what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: The mistake is comparing the returned value from `.getElementById()` (which will be either a DOM node reference or `null`) to the value `true`. Compare to `null` instead.

Comment: The other thing to verify is whether there is actually an element in the DOM with the id "textbox".

Comment: Checking for `null` gives the same behavior as checking for true/false as (probably poorly) explained in the original question. I have verified the element in the DOM with the id "textbox" exists, but only on one of the pages this is designed to work with. On the page where "textbox" does not exist, a different function should be run (`Buzz` from my code above) .

Comment: Note also that the element with the id "textbox" must be in the DOM *when the function runs*.

Comment: I see, that's where I was approaching this wrong then.

Answer (score 0):

document.getElementById returns either null or element. So, comapring both with == or === with true or false will always return false.
You can directly put document.createElement inside if as a condition.
If you still face the issue, I suggest you to put a break point and see how the code is executed.

Sample code for better understanding - https://codepen.io/Yash__/pen/WNzgYvL?editors=1111

```
<h1 id="hai">hai</h1>

if(document.getElementById('hai')){
  console.log("there");
}else{
  console.log("not there")
}
```

Comment: ?? `document.createElement()` doesn't have any relevance to the question (or, for that matter, to your answer).

Comment: Thanks Pointy for pointing that out. Its a typo.

Comment: When testing with your code example in my solution, it behaves the same as when checking for true/false or null. Is it possible other factors in the code could be the culprit?

Comment: Just put a debugger point,  observe the flow and retrace back where it failed.